# SSIS package issue - how to configure the same

Tags: ssis, sendmail

My project scenario is as follows: Suppose we have four HOD and each HOD has some employees under their reporting, and each employee gives a print-out every day.

We need to send sum of print for employee under HOD1 and send email with CSV file (contain Printout detail) attachment to HOD1 through SSIS package, similarly for second HOD2, HOD3 and HOD4 respectively. How can I configure ssis package?

My table structure is like below:

```
HOD_ID  HOD_Name    Emp_Name    dateofprint printout
1       R_Ranga     Ram         2023-11-02  21
2       R_Sanga     shyam       2023-11-02  23
3       R_Kanga     Knhu        2023-11-02  12
4       R_Vanga     Vishal      2023-11-02  10
```

Comment: You can use for each loop container to loop over a list of hod and inside the container use data flow task and email task.

Comment: I am not sure where you are stuck - it rather looks like you have not made a start on the problem. Are you having trouble parsing CSV, or writing a SQL query to collate HOD data? (Your `sendmail` tag is probably wrong by the way - this is for the Sendmail package on *nix systems).

Comment: hi guys, i used for each container to create hod wise .csv files(like for four hod four files created) but the issue is with script task or send mail task , i am not able to figure out next step i.e. hold one HOD data attach hod1 csv file and send email to hod1 then delete hod1's data and jump to next HOD csv file and keep on doing above process for rest of the HOD's.